# Max numbers in a list

Tags: c++, vector, input, output

The first line has two values N and K. N is number of inputs following the initial line, and K is the number of max numbers being sought out.

Example Input:

5 2

6

7

17

11

6

(5 lines of inputs, 2 max values being sought)

Example Output:

17

11

For some reason I am only getting the first output but not the second one.

```
vector<long> vectorAddCheck(vector<long> x, long value){
    if(x.empty()){
        x.push_back(value);
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
            if(x[i] < value){
                x[i] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}


int main() {
    long numLines, numOutputs, temp;
    vector<long> outputList = {};
    cin >> numLines >> numOutputs;

    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; ++i){
        cin >> temp;
        outputList = vectorAddCheck(outputList, temp);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < outputList.size(); i++){
        cout << outputList[i] << endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not add them all to the array, sort it, and peel off the first N?

Comment: You push a value to vector when its length is 0 so your vector's length is maximally 1.

Comment: Gotta get that rare use case for `std::partial_sort`!

Comment: Sleep deprivation has me not thinking straight. That makes this so much simpler. Thank you! @tadman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output vector contains only a single number because of the implementation of `vectorAddCheck`. If the vector is empty you add an item, otherwise you either replace it or just skip the new item. So your vector will always contain a single object.

You could fix it by changing the method to the following implementation:

```
vector<long> vectorAddCheck(vector<long> x, long value){
    if(x.size() < 2){
        x.push_back(value);
    }
    else {
        unsigned min = (x[0] < x[1]) ? 0 : 1;
        if (x[min] < value){
            x[min] = value;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Though, a cleaner implementation is possible:

```
int main() {
    long numLines, numOutputs, temp;
    cin >> numLines >> numOutputs;

    set<long> numbers;
    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; ++i){
        cin >> temp;
        numbers.insert(temp);
    }


    for (set<long>::reverse_iterator it = numbers.rbegin(); it != numbers.rend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;

        --numOutputs;
        if (numOutputs == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```